# New valid date without time in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using google charts and they require real dates for zoom in out etc.

So I have `new Date('31/05/2019')` that converts into same date with 02AM.

Is there a way to force `00:00:00` as time or to even use just date without time?

Now you may ask myself why would I do that when they have `format` option, well I need to use `SteppedAreaChart` that has problem with first day as it it showing that point on 0 axis.

To fix that I needed to add `type="category"`, but now format doesn't work. It skips format option and puts the default one.

```
hAxis: {
  format: 'dd/MM/yy',
  type: 'category'
}
```

I am getting this date from backend: 2019-05-31, And from that I get: May 31, 2019, 2:00:00 AM

Comment: `new Date('31/05/2019')` is not going to produce a valid date btw.

Comment: I am getting this date from backend: 2019-05-31, And from that I get: May 31, 2019, 2:00:00 AM

Comment: use this format instead --> `new Date('05/31/2019')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set hours to 0:00:00 just use `.setHours()`.

Either way, you can omit hours by using `.toDateString()`:

```js
        let today = new Date('2019-05-31')
        today.setHours(0,0,0) //this sets time to 0:00:00 in case you need it
        console.log(today.toDateString()); //Fri May 31 2019
```

Comment: For some reason it doesnt work like you added but it works this way: `(new Date('2019-05-31')).toDateString()`

Comment: That's strange. If you click "Run code snippet" above it works fine. Nonetheless `(new Date('2019-05-31')).toDateString()` should work just fine too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the date to new Date('05/31/2019').

Or can you change the date to a timestamp like this and plot it

```
var date = new Date('05/31/2019');
timestamp = date.getTime();
```